# How to create a empty text box with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, input

I just started learning Bootstrap and build a website.

I was wondering how to create a large empty text input box? So that someone can type in something, such as review for a product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what your looking for.

```
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
</div>
```

```html
  

  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form>
         <div class="form-group">
<h4>Text Area Below with 15 Rows </h4>
  <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="15" id="comment"></textarea>
</div>
      </form>
    </body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I'm looking for.  How do I move the text area to the middle and adjust the width and height of the text area?  thanks a lot.

Comment: please mark post as completed so the author gets rewarded for it :)

Comment: Bootstrap's Default Settings. Form controls automatically receive some global styling with Bootstrap: All textual <input> , <textarea> , and <select> elements with class .form-control have a width of 100%. You would have to remove this to control width and add some css to move text area too middle, for the height you can modify the rows attribute, the more rows the more height, hopefully this helps

Comment: Yes that helps.  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

According to [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups), you can size an input with input-* classes:

```
<input class="form-control input-sm" type="text"/>
<input class="form-control input-md" type="text"/>
<input class="form-control input-lg" type="text"/>
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputdefault">Default input</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="inputdefault" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputlg">input-lg</label>
      <input class="form-control input-lg" id="inputlg" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputsm">input-sm</label>
      <input class="form-control input-sm" id="inputsm" type="text">
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the textarea tag.

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

You can either add attributes in the textarea tag or use CSS to change the size of the textarea.

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>

textarea { width : 100px; min-height : 50px;}
```